# go test causes no such file or directory

Tags: go

I'm creating a RESTFull API in Go and securing my application with [JWT](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519). I'm using [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) algorithm so I have `private` and `public` key pair. In order to create a JWT token I have to read them.

First of all this is my project structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── config
│   └── config.go
├── config.json
├── data
│   ├── init.sql
│   ├── keys
│   │   ├── 256
│   │   │   ├── keys-256.md
│   │   │   ├── private-key.pem
│   │   │   └── public-key.pem
│   │   └── 512
│   │       ├── keys-512.md
│   │       ├── private-key.pem
│   │       └── public-key.pem
│   └── ....
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── handler
│   ├── auth.go
│   ├── auth_test.go
│   ├── healthcheck.go
│   └── healthcheck_test.go
│   
├── main.go
└── security
    └── token
        ├── generator.go
        └── parser.go
```

This is the source file where I read private key file as you can see I'm using [init function](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#init) in go so I'll read the key file once and use it every time I need it.

#### generator.go

```
package security

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt"
    // ...
)

var privateKeyPath = "data/keys/512/private-key.pem"
var privateKey *ecdsa.PrivateKey

func init() {
    printWorkingDirectory()
    privateKey = getECDSAPrivateKey(readPrivateKeyFile())
}



func getECDSAPrivateKey(data []byte) *ecdsa.PrivateKey {
        ecdsaKey, err := jwt.ParseECPrivateKeyFromPEM(data);
    if  err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse ECDSA private key: %v", err)
    }
    return ecdsaKey
}

func readPrivateKeyFile() []byte {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(privateKeyPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can not read private key file: %v", err)
    }
    return data;
}
func printWorkingDirectory() {
    mydir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Working directory: ", mydir)
}
//...
```

Key path is relative to root directory of project `var privateKeyPath = "data/keys/512/private-key.pem"`

When I run `go run .` in the root directory, everything fine.

When I run `go test ./...` Golang creates a temporary directory and runs my test in there basically this causes a problem.
Here is the result of `go test ./...`:

```
✗ go test -v ./...

Working directory is:  /var/folders/wk/ncyvbtdj3w57cr5j1v46x7dr39dz_l/T/go-build4211274972/b150
Initing db manger
2021/10/28 19:13:47 Can not read private key file: open data/keys/512/private-key.pem: no such file or directory
FAIL    mydomain/myprojectname/handler   1.274s
```

Actually I'm a Java Developer and I'm new in Go

Simply in Java we have `classpath` and [it](https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) saves the day.

I don't want to use `absolute path` because I have Dockerfile and if I use absolute path in my local computer it will hurt me in docker container.

My question is:

**How can I use a relative path which works with `go run` and `go test` commands.**

Comment: Paths are relative to the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), not a source file.  The source directory may not be available at runtime. Consider [embedding](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) the file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because when you run `go run`, or for that matter when you run your built application, the working directory is inherited from your environment. But when a package is tested, the working directory is always the package directory.

One quick solution would be to have a copy of your `data` directory inside your `security` directory as a test fixture, this would also allow you to use a specific key for testing.

A better solution is to think about how you will load your key in production. This `init()` function in your `security` package is quite inflexible because:

1. In production, your key must be in a specific location relative to the working directory only.
2. You cannot influence the behaviour of the `init()` function in tests because `init()` is always run before tests start.

My recommendation would be that rather than using `init()`, you pass either the literal key, or a path to the key into class/classes in the `security` package from `main` when you instantiate them. This way your key can be located anywhere when in production and your tests can be directed to use a key in the source tree relative to that package's directory.

Comment: Path to the key, in an environment variable or runtime argument.  Passing the key literal moves the secret to the location of the invocation, which makes security harder.  Better to put it in a file.